# How to translate 'see' at the end of a sentence?

Tags: traducción

### Español

¿Como se puede traducir 'see' al final de una frase, como en

> I have just started learning Spanish, see.
>   (Acabo de comenzar a aprender español, ...)

### English

How can one translate 'see' at the end of a sentence, as in

> I have just started learning Spanish, see.

Comment: Relevant meta post for questions of this sort: http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1407/12

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word "see" here is used to emphasize that the speaker wants to ensure that the message was understood by his audience.  In english, it really should be written as a question "..., you see?"

Understanding it from this perspective, you can translate in a variety of ways.  I would recommend "..., me entiendes?"

Comment: Si el uso de «..., see» se puede entender, como tú dices, como una abreviación de «..., you see?», una posible expresión cercana en español sería más bien «..., ¿sabes?», antes que «..., ¿me entiendes?».

También se me ocurre que quizá «Oye, acabo de comenzar un curso de español» podría ser (aunque el «oye» suele ir al principio de la frase antes que al final).

Comment: @Paloma: Claro, hay muchas posibilidades que podriamos sustituir! :) Lo mas importante es entender la funcion que "see" lleva en esta frase.

Comment: Sí, @Paul, llevas razón.

Comment: En Chile usamos _¿cachay?_. "Estoy aprendiendo inglés, ¿cachay?".

Answer (score 7):

You could use:

> ¿Me sigues?
>
> ¿Me entiendes? / ¿entiendes?
>
> ¿Comprendes?
>
> ¿Vale?
>
> ¿Ves?

Comment: My catalonian cousin used to say "Captas?" (probably his Spanish was influenced by some expression in Catalonian, but we all understood him).

Comment: To me, as a speaker of southern British English, 'see' sounds quite rude or aggressive. I suppose it depends on the tone of voice.

Answer (score 1):

> Fíjate que acabo de comenzar a aprender español.
>
> ¿Sabes qué? Acabo de ...
>
> Sabes que acabo de ...
>
> ¿Adivina qué? Acabo de ...
>
> Te voy a contar, acabo de ...

I don't like the use of **`me entiendes`** or similar ones. Sounds like the English **`you know what I mean`**. It is a very common "crutch" but I find it kind of rude, like you are speaking with someone who is slow to understand. It sounds different when you really mean **`Do you understand?`** maybe because what you are explaining, or the way you have explained it so far, is hard to understand, *you know what I mean ?*

And then, all kinds of combinations, like:

> Me quitaron las cordales, ¿te había contado?
>
> En estos canales hay lagartos, ¿sabías?
>
> Tengo tamaña picada en la espalda, fíjate !

**Fíjate** is a very common expression in Mexico. It conveys the idea of paying attention, or taking note of something. I think it would be the closest translation for your **, see** in your question.

And the answer would not be complete without the reference to the phrase made popular by [La Chilindrina:](http://www.lachilindrina.com/indexch.php) **Fíjate, fíjate, fíjate !**

Answer (score 1):

I have just started learning Spanish, see. 
See means "ves", and u can use it this way:

Recién empecé a aprender español, ¿ves?

I wouldn't suggest using "¿vale?", "¿captas?", "¿me sigues?" because that's informal and it's used only by spanish people, so if you want to use spanish in south america you shouldn't use them.

More formal is "¿entiende usted?", you can use "¿vale?", "¿captas?", "¿me sigues?" only if you are talking to a friend.